# "Insecure HTTP request is unsupported" Error in Scala

Tags: java, scala, http, compiler-errors, sbt

I am getting the following error when attempting to run `sbt run` to run my Scala code:

`insecure HTTP request is unsupported 'http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("typesafe-releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true), or by using allowInsecureProtocol in repositories file`

This is strange because it was working perfectly fine last week and I have changed nothing in the code. I have tried adding `("typesafe-releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)` in my `build.sbt` file and resolver file, installing Java11, deleting my project folder, and completely reclone my code from the repository but nothing is working. I am using Visual Studios but have also tried on IntelliJ and get the same error.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I have changed nothing and now suddenly my code doesn't compile anymore. Further details:

sbt.version = 1.4.0

Scala code runner version 2.12.10

My current built.sbt (please note that I did not have the resolve part added before, when my code was working fine. It was added as an attempt to resolve the issue but did not work):

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

name := "name"
organization := "org"
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.1",
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo-bson-api" % "0.20.11",
"org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "3.0.0",
"com.ibm.db2.jcc" % "db2jcc" % "db2jcc4"
)

resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
```

**EDIT:**
I've discovered that this error occurs regardless of project, and even occurs when I simply run sbt by itself.

Comment: Do you still have SSLHandshakeException after upgrading java?
What versions of scala/sbt do you use?
Some more information and error details would be helpful.

Comment: @tentacle thanks for your comments. None of the listed things above made any difference, I still got the same error. Additional version details added to the above. The error occurs after: `[info] loading project definition `

Comment: @TomerShetah The issue is that I never needed the resolver part in the first place, and my code was compiling and running completely fine. I have tried and added the resolver resolver part is below anyway: `resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases")`

Comment: @TomerShetah I tried, this doesn't work unfortunately. Update: I've discovered the error occurs regardless of which project I'm opening, and still occurs by simply entering the SBT environment with the "sbt" command

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you try deleting ~/.sbt folder? I had a repositories file in this folder that had HTTP references to the typesafe repo and deleting this folder resolved those sbt HTTP errors.

Comment: `rm ~/.sbt/repositories` was enough in my case.

Comment: I deleted the target folder. I was running clean on builder but was not enough

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else using an Intellij setup with this issue, see below

Environment:

- Scala 2.12.7
- Intellij Ultimate
- JVM 11

The issue seems to be a clash between the Intellij IDE SBT plugin ( still on 1.3.2 ) and what seems to be a silent update of sbt.

Running sbt ( version 1.4.3 ) in a terminal instead of using the built in plugin fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [repo.typesafe.com](https://repo.typesafe.com/), you can add to your sbt:

```
Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases")
```

or:

```
Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
```

Depends whether you are using `Ivy` or not.

The reason to this warning is the fact that you are using `http` and not `https`. From `sbt` 1.4.0 [release notes](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.4.0):

> HTTP resolvers require explicit opt-in using .withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)

[This](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/5593) is the PR that added it.

Comment: OP has made it clear that there's explicit opt-out in the build.

Comment: @tentacle, the error message clearly shows that `"typesafe-releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"` is part of `build.sbt`. This is the reason to the warning, and replacing it with `Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases")` will solve it.

Comment: @TomerShetah Thanks for your input, however this did not solve the issue. Additionally I am now getting "Failed to connect with build server, no functionality will work. See logs for more details." after attempting to rebuild build.sbt

Comment: @TomerShetah thanks for your suggestions. Please see working solution above by SSam.

Comment: resolvers += ("Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/")
.withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)

Answer (score 1):

Had to edit `~/.sbt/repositories` to use https.