# Problem Running a Play Framework App 2.2.1 with SBT 0.13.18 on Mac Big Sur

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I am new to Play and SBT.
I am trying to run an existing application which is based on a Mac Big Sur OS :

- Play 2.2.1
- SBT 0.13.0
- Java 1.7

build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.18
```

plugins.sbt

```
  // Comment to get more information during initialization
    logLevel := Level.Warn
    
    // The Typesafe repository
    resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

    
    // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
    
    
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.9.4")
```

The application was originally built in 0.13.0, but I could not find that binary anywhere.

When I cd to my application top project directory and run:

```
play run
```

OR

```
play help
```

OR

```
sbt --version
```

I get the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.18 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.18

    ==== maven-central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.18/sbt-0.13.18.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.18: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.18: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /Applications/Development/play-2.2.1/framework/sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.18
```

Ideally, I would like to use the 0.13.0 SBT, but its not available anywhere.
I have tried SBT 1.4.4, that progress a bit, but the existing dependencies in plugins.sbt is not in the [https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"](https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/%22).
Notice, I had to change http to https to use the 1.4.4 from https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

With SBT 1.4.4 And updating repo to https, i got the following error:

```
xxx@MacBook-Pro-xxx trunk % play help                                
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.4 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_271)
[info] loading settings for project trunk-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /Applications/Development/capify/trunk/project
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-aspectj:0.9.4 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.2.1 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-aspectj;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.9.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-aspectj_2.12_1.0/0.9.4/sbt-aspectj-0.9.4.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-aspectj/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.9.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-aspectj/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.9.4/ivys/ivy.xm
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-aspectj_2.12_1.0/0.9.4/sbt-aspectj-0.9.4.pom
[error] Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.2.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.2.1/sbt-plugin-2.2.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.2.1/ivys/ivy.xm
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.2.1/sbt-plugin-2.2.1.pom
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:53)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:103)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:116)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:116)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:97)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:130)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:3485)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-aspectj;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.9.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-aspectj_2.12_1.0/0.9.4/sbt-aspectj-0.9.4.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-aspectj/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.9.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-aspectj/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.9.4/ivys/ivy.xm
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-aspectj_2.12_1.0/0.9.4/sbt-aspectj-0.9.4.pom
[error] Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.2.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.2.1/sbt-plugin-2.2.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.2.1/ivys/ivy.xm
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.2.1/sbt-plugin-2.2.1.pom
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

Comment: I would recommend to use sbt 1.4.4 which has major improvements over sbt 0.13 . See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64989874/2359227) how to add typesafe in the sbt 1.4.4.

Comment: Please, help with the syntax. The current code was developed in windows and has the following as stated in question above: resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
. The syntax for the post you refered me to looks different i.e. resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases") 
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases")

Comment: It seems the 1.4.4 SBT is not compatible wit Play 2.2.1. I have updated the plugins.sbt

with resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases") , but I am still getting Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-aspectj;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.9.4
[error]   Not found

Comment: can you upgrade play to latest?

Comment: You can use play 2.8.2, with sbt 1.4.4 and scala 2.13 2.13.3

Comment: If not, try downgrading scala to 2.11.12

Comment: Hello Tom, pls confirm that to downgrade to 2.11.12. I need to update plugins.sbt. By changing     addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
 to     addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.11.12"). ? Are u suggesting that if the client insist on using play 2.2.1, I could use scala 2.11.12 with play 2.2.1? Any ideas what version of SBT and Scala will go with 2.2.1. I am stuck now!

Comment: No. You need to update your `build.sbt`. Find there `scalaVersion`, and make sure you assign there 2.11.12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225110/discussion-between-tomer-shetah-and-mega).